# Apache reverse proxy only works in first url level ( /api but not /api/getdata )

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-server, nestjs

I'm trying to set up an Apache reverse proxy on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

I have a node server (NestJS) on port 3000 which exposes a hello world response on the base url and some data on /getdata.

My Apache default conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location /api>
            ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

When and I'm trying to contact it directly through `http://11.22.33.44.55/api` I get the hello world response, but when I try to access `http://11.22.33.44.55/api/getdata` I get an empty 500 response.

I feel that it probably is the reverse proxy that's causing the problem but I guess it could be the node server somehow as well.

Anybody recognizes this issue?

Comment: Which version of `Nestjs` you are using out there?

Comment: @DavidR I use 5.0.1

Comment: Can you please post your `getdata` code?

Comment: If you get 500, there should be an error, either in Apache or Node log.

Comment: I believe you would need "<Location /api/*>"